# POST request with JSON Body Serialization

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I have one specific issue, which I'm not able to handle.

I'm using HTTP Get API request and I'm getting JSON string, which I'm deserializing, this works perfectly. But then, I need to reuse just two  pairs of this JSON file, but it needs to be pasted as JSON body for POST request. Let me show you the example:

Output of GET API Request:

```
{
  "message":{
      "value":[
         {
           "Reference":null,
           "Key":"abc",
           "IssueNumber":123
         },
         {
           "Reference":null,
           "Key":"def",
           "IssueNumber":345
         }
       ]
     }
   }
```

So now Im able to deserialize this JSON string (i.e.: jsonString("value)(0)("Key") and I will get "abc").

But now, I have no idea, how to serialize this deserialized object to use ReviewStatus and Key. This POST request JSON body looks like that:

```
{
   "newStatus":"New"
   "queueItems": [
     {
        "Key":"abc"
        "IssueNumber":123
     },
     {
        "Key":"def"
        "IssueNumber":456
     }
  ]
}
```

For loop works for me, but in that case, I will do API call for each item instead of doing just one POST API call. What would be the best solution in your opinion? I was trying to use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert (SerializeObject Method), but it didn't work for me as I expected. I'm pretty sure, that there needs to be something much easier, but I need your help.

Thanks for any advice.
Frantisek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write two split species models, one for Receive JSON Modle, another for Response JSON Model.

**Receive Modle**

```
public class Value
{
    public object Reference { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int IssueNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public List<Value> value { get; set; }
}

public class ReciveModel
{
    public Message message { get; set; }
}
```

**Response Model**

```
public class QueueItem
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int IssueNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseModel
{
    public string newStatus { get; set; }
    public List<QueueItem> queueItems { get; set; }
}
```

Receive your JSON data and Deserialize to  `ReciveModel` object, then let the data into another instance `ResponseModel`

final, you use  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` to serialize then instance to be JSON data.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReciveModel>(JsonData);
var res = new ResponseModel() {
    newStatus = "New",
    queueItems = obj.message.value.Select(x => new QueueItem() {
        IssueNumber = x.IssueNumber,
        Key = x.Key
    }).ToList()
};
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
```

**Result**

```
{"newStatus":"New","queueItems":[{"Key":"abc","IssueNumber":123},{"Key":"def","IssueNumber":345}]}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/umfVGM)

**Note**

There are two way can create model easily.

- You can use Web Essentials in Visual Studio, use Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as class, you can easier to know the relation between Json and model.
- If you can't use Web Essentials you can instead of use http://json2csharp.com/ online JSON to Model class.

You can try to use those models to carry your JSON Format.

Comment: Hey D-Shih, thanks a lot for your detailed answer! It seems pretty straightforward and your Note will make my life much easier :). I will try it tomorrow and I hope, it will work :). Thanks.